# How to automatically performance test just the web UI layer?

Tags: performance, web-application, jenkins

We've setup the Jenkins-performance-plugin to run our JMeter tests automatically.  However we'ld also like to test the Web UI layer for performance.  We've found tools and websites, but we're looking for something more easily automated so we can run it from Jenkins.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for something easier than JMeter to use with Jenkins?

Comment: @user246 No, we're looking for How to automatically performance test the web UI layer?, as apposed to JMeter, which actually only tests the server performance.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the distinction, are you trying to performance-test the web UI in isolation, i.e. by mocking all the business logic?  Or do you mean something else?  Perhaps it would help to mention a tool/website you've found that performance tests the UI layer" without performance testing the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I want yslow with phantomjs.  There are setup instructions for Jenkins at http://yslow.org/phantomjs/